# ODOO : Set specific value of an attribute in attrs

Tags: odoo, odoo-8, attrs.xml

I am trying to display attachment in the form view. Based on the type of attachment I want to change the value of widget. If attachment is an image then `widget="image"`. 

My doubt is if we write something like this:

```
attrs="{'invisible' : [('state', 'in', ('new','assigned'))] , 'readonly' : [('state', 'not in', 'assigned')]}"
```

This will set the invisible and read_only properties to true since they are boolean or have just two values. How can we set an attribute to a specific value.
Also, can we use widget to display video attachment in the form view?

Answer (score 0):

You can create two fields with different widgets and make them visible based on the condition in your domain

```
<field name="attachement" attrs="{'invisible' : [('state', 'in', ('new','assigned'))] , 'readonly' : [('state', 'not in', 'assigned')]}" widget="image" />

<field name="attachement" attrs="{'invisible' : [('state', 'not in', ('new','assigned'))] , 'readonly' : [('state', 'not in', 'assigned')]}" />
```

At any point in time only the field with the right widget would be shown based on the condition in your domain.

As for your second question. personally i've never had the need to embed a video within a form in Odoo.

but embedding `<video></video>` tags should work

Comment: If i recall correct Odoo will show the field content in the last field definition in a view. So the the first field definition should be useless. I think making the field invisible won't deal with that behaviour.

Comment: I really don't get what you mean....but from the domain filter only one field should be visible at a time, not both of them

Comment: It's hard to explain, sorry. Defining a field twice or more in a view will odoo only fill the fields content (e. g. a string for a char field) of the last defined field. But i don't know if invisibility changes this.

Comment: And more: the other fields are always empty.

Comment: I tried this but it does not work in case of an image. The image doesn't show up but a download link is provided in the other cases.